# Call an array whose value is between quotes: getElementById("'"+CB[x]+"'")

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, tags

I need to call either a array like below:

```
ONone = document.getElementById("'"+CB[x]+"'");
```

or a property value like so:

```
 var ONone = document.getElementById("'"+animateSector.named.id+"'");
```

the above values i.e (CB[x] and animateSector.named.id) alert the value that i need however when there called in the

```
(document.getElementById("'"+CB[x]+"'")
```

and

```
(document.getElementById("'"+animateSector.named.id+"'")
```

they return a null console error saying

> Onone is null

Comment: What does "call an array" mean? What does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` doesn't accept a CSS selector, it accepts an **ID**. So even if the `id` would need to be quoted in CSS, it doesn't matter, because this isn't CSS.

Without seeing your HTML it's impossible to be sure, but:

Get the element whose `id` is whatever is in `CB[x]`, or whatever is in `animateSector.named.id`:

```
ONone = document.getElementById(CB[x]);
ONone = document.getElementById(animateSector.named.id);
```

Get the element whose `id` **is** `CB[x]`:

```
ONone = document.getElementById('CB[x]');
```

Get a list of elements whose **`name`** is `CB[]`, and then get entry #`x` from that list:

```
list = document.querySelectorAll('[name="CB[]"]');
entryX = list[x];
```

`querySelectorAll`, as the name implies, *does* accept a CSS selector, and returns all matching elements in a list.